# ES6 filter an array of objects retrieving a field that is an empty array or does not contain certain value

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am trying to filter the following array

```
const matches = [
  {
    "match": "1",
    "teams": [
      [
        { "name": "david"},
        { "name": "tom"}
      ],
      [
        { "name": "liam"},
        { "name": "noah"}
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": "2",
    "teams": [
      [
        { "name": "david"},
        { "name": "tom"}
      ],
      [
        { "name": "oliver"},
        { "name": "elijah"}
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": "3",
    "teams": []
  }
]
```

I want to retrieve the objects where the teams array is empty, or "oliver" does not belong to the teams. It should retrieve match "1" and "3"

I tried the following

```
matches.filter(match => match.teams.length === 0 || !match.teams.includes({ name: "oliver" })

matches.filter(match => match.teams.length === 0 || !match.teams.some(team => team.name === "oliver" })
```

but I am getting the 3 objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match.teams` is an  array of arrays of players

try this

```js
matches.filter(match => 
    match.teams.length === 0 ||
    match.teams.every(team => 
        team.every(player => player.name !== "oliver" )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// use array.flat method. teams is arrays of arrays    
const result=matches.filter(match=>{
        if(!match.teams.length){
            return true;
        }
    
          const teamArray=match.teams.flat(1);
          console.log(teamArray);
        const search=teamArray.find(player=>player.name!=="oliver");
            if(search){
            return true;
        }
          return false;
        
    });
```